# Verilog if else if construct

Tags: verilog, hdl, synthesis, system-verilog

I have verilog code that looks like this

```vhdl
begin
  if (condition)
       if(condition2)
       else if(condition3)
       else if(condition4)
  else
   ..logic..
end
```

This code compiles and simulates. My question is how would the simulator interpret the last else branch? Would it consider the else as a part of the nested *if-else-if* construct or the outer *if* construct.

Also, would synthesis result in an inferred latch for which of those constructs?

Programming languages generally do no mandate the use of else branch even for a if..else if construct.

But I want to know how Verilog being a HDL handles this? I could not find any specific mention in the LRM.

Comment: Just put `begin` and `end` in to make the code unambiguous, then you don't have to worry (or remember the next time you read your code) what the standard says. (But my guess is, it goes with the inner `if`)

Comment: How do you even know whether the first `else if` goes with the inner or outer `if`? And if you know it goes with the inner `if`, why do you think the rule for `else if` might be different from the rule for `else`?

Comment: @Photon I agree there are ways to avoid such errors by practice of begin..end etc. But suppose this did go in an actual design I'm trying to understand the implication on inferred logic. The else if always goes with the second if because the construct always has an immediate preceding if, but the else is not mandatory.

Comment: Doesn't `else` also always have an immediately preceding `if`?

Comment: Yes but it also goes to an immediately preceding else if which is why I have this question.

Comment: Your second `else if` is also following an `else if` rather than a bare `if`. Do you know whether it goes with the inner or outer `if`? I still am not seeing why `else` and `else if` could be considered different.

Comment: @The Photon that's a valid point. Verilog being extremely sensitive to conditional constructs (due to possible inferred latches) I was thinking maybe there would be stricter checking by the compiler/simulator. Having begin..end is the only way I can logically tell but I'm still curious about what's happens under the hood while simulating/synthesizing this piece of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look at the BNF to understand how code is parsed. Indenting makes code easier to read, but is meaningless for the compiler

```
conditional_statement ::= // from A.6.6
          [ unique_priority ] if ( cond_predicate ) statement_or_null
          { else if ( cond_predicate ) statement_or_null }
          [ else statement_or_null ]
```

And a `begin/end` is considered a statement, as well as another nested conditional_statement. So your code is illegal because there is no statement_or_null after `if(condition4)` Adding a null `;` would make the last `else` go with the last `if`.

Once you have a completely legal `always` block, a synthesis tool looks at the flow of variable references across all possible branches. If there's a possibility that a variable could be read without first being written, then is gets implemented as a latch. It's a bit more complicated than that; do read your synthesis tool manual.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. What does BNF stand for?

Comment: @RajeshS BNF is Backus-Naur Form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Comment: I missed out in representing it but I meant there would be single line logic after each of those if/else-if statements.

Comment: @dave_59 could you please add a link to the BNF document for Verilog/SV as well? I got to go through a rudimentary document by a Google search but not the whole document. I think this was the missing link that can help me clear out such interpretation questions. The LRM doesn't help in these cases.

Comment: It's in the LRM Annex A